# How to submit two php forms to one location

Tags: php, forms

I have two php forms, both for registration means (enter name, username, password etc). My first registration form (reg1.php) contains the basic inputs as I mentioned above and then I have a second registration form (reg2.php) that includes checkboxes where the form would ask the user other questions before finalizing their sign up.

What I am having trouble with is that when I enter data into my inputs in the first registration form, then proceed to the next registration page and fill that out and click Sign Up, my output on my server only obtains the information I inputted in the second registration page, not the first.

How can I get both inputted data from the two registration pages to appear together? I have been told about POSTBACK to help with this but I am not all that familiar with how to use it.

First php page:

```
<body>
<?php include("menu.php"); ?>
<div id="main">
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<table style="width:300px">
<form name="Rego" method="post" action="rego2.php">
<tr>
<td><label>Name:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Username:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="username"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Password:</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" id="pass" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Confirm Password:</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="conpassword" id="conpass"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p><input class="button" type="submit" value="Next Page">
<input class="button" type="reset" value="Reset"></p></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Second php page

```
<body>
<?php include("menu.php"); ?>
<div id="main">
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<table>
<form name="Rego" method="post" action="http://myserver...">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="Agree to T&C">I agree to the <a href="tnc.php">Terms and Conditions</a><br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="No Criminal Records">I have no criminal associations<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p><input class="button" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
<input class="button" type="reset" value="Reset"></p></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Three answers already, and all mentioning hidden form fields to transport the data … that is something you should _not_ do, at least not for sensitive data like the password the user entered. Store it in the session instead (as Mike W also suggested).

Answer (score 2):

When the first form is submitted either store the data in a $_SESSION variable and retrieve it when you process the second form, or write it to hidden `<input>` elements on your second form and retrieve it from  the `$_GET` or `$_POST` array

Answer (score 1):

In 2nd input form you take first inout from value  and keep those one as hidden.

and 2nd input form you should

```
<body>
<?php include("menu.php"); ?>
<div id="main">
<h2>Sign Up</h2>
<table>
<form name="Rego" method="post" action="http://myserver...">

<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="<?php echo  $_POST['fname'];?> " />
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo  $_POST['username'];?> " />
<input type="hidden" name="passowrd" value="<?php echo  $_POST['password'];?> " />
<input type="hidden" name="conpassowrd" value="<?php echo  $_POST['conpassword'];?> " />
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="Agree to T&C">I agree to the <a href="tnc.php">Terms and Conditions</a><br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="No Criminal Records">I have no criminal associations<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p><input class="button" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
<input class="button" type="reset" value="Reset"></p></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the second page, you can get the post data from page 1 and set it in a hidden field like this, say the fname:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php echo $_POST['fname'] ?>">
```

When you submit from the second page, you can catch this data in the destination page, say

```
$_POST['fname']
```